# Show console until application start running?

Tags: python, console, pyqt5, pyinstaller

When I create PyQt application through Pyinstaller, I know that `--noconsole` will hide the console. However, is there a way to show console until the actual application starts? In other words, console will be automatically closed once the application is up and running.

I want to implement such because I have application of loading lots of DB from MySQL and I want to let user know through console that application is loading DB by inserting 'print' in my application. I would really appreciate it if there is any way to achieve what I want through Pyinstaller or Python.

Comment: I don't know if there is function for this but I expect it doesn't exists - but I would rather use `PyQt` to display all messages - it looks better. You can redirect `sys.stdout` to widget in `PyQt` and then all `print()` will display in this widget.

Comment: @furas Thank you for your comment. Yes, I just created the bootup GUI to use  sys.stdout. Thanks!